guardar un en campo de la base de datos, varios datos de un input
Quiero traer varios datos de input en la hoja usernew.php, y guardarlos en la base de datos, en un campo llamado categorías.
En el **from, creé un input dinámico donde se agregan sin problema con javascript, pero a la hora de recuperar los datos, no logro que lo capte y lo guarde, me sale un error.
No sé como capturar los datos y guaradarlos en el campo de la base con el php, recorrerlo y llevarlo a la bd, allí capturo unas etiquetas tag con las categorias, eso funciona, en el from.. normal, las capturo con el
name="tags_input"

lo envio por post en el formulario, y lo recupero con
$categorias=limpiar_cadena($_POST['tags_input']); 

lo recorro con el for o foreach, para guardarlo con comas intermediasm en la base, gracias.
error que arroja:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webp/webmain/php/usuario_guardar.php:297 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webp/webmain/php/usuario_guardar.php on line 297
ejemplo con: var_dump($_POST);
**array(9) {     
    ["idioma"]=> string(10) "Papiamento" 
    ["dni"]=> string(13) "1223345566678" 
    ["pais"]=> string(7) "Albania" 
    ["nombres"]=> string(6) "efverg" 
    ["tags"]=> string(41) "Dancers, Entrepreneurs, Cosplay, For Kids"  ["apellidos"]=> string(10) "efhefheuhr" 
    ["email"]=> string(24) "kjfjbf45555bfs@gmail.com" 
    ["usuario_clave_1"]=> string(7) "1234567" 
    ["usuario_clave_2"]=> string(7) "1234567" } string(0) ""

Warning: Undefined array key "tags_input" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webp/webmain/php/usuario_guardar.php on line 298
<!---html--->
<form action="./php/usuario_guardar.php" method="POST" class="FormularioAjax" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="column">
                <label>Categoria</label><br>
                    <div class=container>
                    <div class="custom-select">
                                <div class="select-box">
                                    <input type="text" class="tags_input" name="tags" hidden />
                                    <div class="selected-options">                                   
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="arrow">  <!--div de clase flecha-->
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                    </div>          
                                </div>
        
                                
                                <div class="options">
                                    <div class="option-search-tags" name="categorias">
                                        <input type="text" class="search-tags" name="tags_input" 
                                        placeholder="Seleccione max 5 categorias."/>
                                        <button type="button" class="clear"><i
                                        class="delete is-small"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="option all-tags"
                                    data-value="All"> select All</div>
                                    
                                    <?php                   
                                    $categorias=conexion();
                                        $categorias=$categorias->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
                                        if($categorias->rowCount()>0){
                                            $categorias=$categorias->fetchAll();
                                            foreach($categorias as $row){
                                                echo '<option class="option" data-value="'.$row['cat_name'].'" >'.                                              $row['cat_name'].'</option>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                        $categorias=null;
                                        ?>
                                             
                                </div>                 
                            <span class="tag_error_msg error"></span>
                        </div>
        
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>               
                    <p class="has-text-centered">
                        <button type="submit" class="button is-info is-rounded">Guardar</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            
            //////hoja guardar// usuario guardar.php//////
            
            $categorias=limpiar_cadena($_POST['tags_input']);
            
                 $datos='';                
                
                     foreach($i=0; $i > count($_POST['categorias']); $i++){     
                        $datos .= $_POST['categorias'][$i].",";     
                }
                    $datos= rtrim($datos.'","');}
                     echo "datos seleccionados". $datos;
            
                        
          
        /*== Guardando datos ==*/
            $guardar_usuario=conexion();
            $guardar_usuario=$guardar_usuario->prepare("INSERT INTO user_model
            (categorias)
            VALUES(:categoria)");
        
            $marcadores=[
                
                ":categoria"=>$datos,
                   
                
            ];
        
            $guardar_usuario->execute($marcadores);



Hola. Hay varias cosas. El name="categorias" debe esta en el input para que se serialice al mandar el form. Si el input no tiene name no se va a enviar el dato. Por cierto, no se ve ningún formulario declarado en el código que nos compartes. Luego, no te cobran por cada variable declarada. LLamar todo el rato $categorias a elementos distintos es una pésima práctica y no ayuda a la comprensión del código, considera diversificar el nombrado de los elementos. Dicho eso, ¿si pones un var_dump($categorias); justo antes del foreach qué muestra?

Por otra parte, no se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres hacer. Por ejemplo, ¿cuál es el propósito del último bloque de código que muestras en la pregunta y de qué modo se relaciona ese código con el formulario? Considera poner el html completo del form.

@A.Cedano: Hola una disculpa casi no sube la pregunta y al copiar la información no me di cuenta, pero este es la conexion del formulario, que va en la hoja de guardar $categorias=limpiar_cadena($_POST['tags_input']); el ultimo bloque es la interaccion que quiero hacer con la base de datos para que guarde, al poner el var_dum no me muestra nada..no entendi lo de categorias de llamar todo de esa forma, soy novato y por ende pregunte si algo obviamente debe estar mal, podrias referirte siendo mas explicito te agradezco

No entendí del todo tu anterior comentario. Resumo lo que quise decir. 1. No se ve el código completo. No vemos dónde empieza y termina el form; 2. Para que un input se mande con el formulario debe tener una etiqueta name, el input que muestras en la pregunta no tiene dicha etiqueta; 3. Con lo de $categorias me refiero a que nombras varias cosas con ese nombre, por ejemplo: $categorias=conexion();, luego $categorias=$categorias->query ..., luego $categorias=$categorias->fetchAll(); Son tres cosas distintas: la conexión, el resultado de la consulta y los datos ...

... Luego, no se entiende del todo qué es lo que quieres hacer ni cómo el último bloque de código se relaciona con el primero. No lo expliques en un comentario, pulsa en [edit] y aclara el problema y el contexto.

@A.Cedano, vale ya edite lo mas completo de acuerdo a como se estoy creando, entonces: 1. en la imagen esta el error y input que muestro en el navegador, alli capturo unas etiquetas tag con las categorias eso funciona en el from.. normal, las caprturo con el name="tags_input" lo envio por post en el formulario, lo recupero con $categorias=limpiar_cadena($_POST['tags_input']);   lo recorro con el for o foreach, para guardarlo con comas intermedias en la base, pero no se que sucede porque no se comprobar el programa y no realiza lo que yo quiero, espero se entienda lo que quiero

el html y el php estan en el mismo sitio???

@FranciscoNuñezIALover Hola, no sr estan en diferente hoja

tienes alguna idea si se usa algun pluggin o libreria para que el html soporte que agregues tags a un input???

@FranciscoNuñezIALover pues lo que hago es enlazar al formulario una hoja de java script para que haga toda la funcionalidad en el formulario.. traigo de la base la consulta, me muestra un listado alli los elijo y los va reservando dentro del input este funciona sin problema

Yo sigo sin ver el form en tu código. Por favor, no aclares nada en comentarios ahora, mejor pulsa en [edit] y reformula la pregunta explicando la lógica que estás siguiendo y poniendo el código. Los mensajes de error también los puedes poner como texto. Para una depuración rápida pon un var_dump($_POST); al inicio del código donde estarías recibiendo los datos del formulario y dinos qué muestra. Como ya te dije, si no pones un name a los elementos del form cuyos datos quieres enviar, no vas a recibir esos datos.

El error dice que está en la línea 297 del archivo usuario_guardar.php. Indica también en la pregunta qué es lo que hay en esa línea. Tampoco veo eso en tu pregunta.

@A.Cedano no se que pasa pego el codigo y desoderna ya la habia incluido, bueno esta corregido... en la linea 297 esta el for  /for($i=0; $i > count($_POST['category']); $i++){ /.. en esta linea comienza el codigo for que muestro en el ejemplo y en el ejemplo te pongo los errores incluyendo el ultimo que me pides

Si observas la salida que arroja var_dump($_POST); verás que no hay ninguna clave (valores de la izquierda) llamada category, por eso te está tirando el Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given al intentar esto for($i=0; $i > count($_POST['category']); $i++){ por lo dicho, $_POST['category'] no existe, es null.  ...

... Tienes también un Undefined array key "tags_input"* por el mismo motivo, en $_POST no hay ninguna clave llamada tags_input, en cambio, sí hay una clave llamada tags. Conviene saber que cuando se manda un formulario, en este caso por el método POST, lo que ocurre es que se crea en la super global $_POSTun array asociativo cuyas claves equivaldrán a lo que tengas en la etiqueta name de los elementos, asociadas esas claves a los valores que tenga cada elemento respectivo. Para buscar un  $_POST['category'] debes tener en el formulario un elemento con name="category" ...

Y para buscar un $_POST['tags_input'] debes tener en el formulario un elemento con name="tags_input" y esos elementos deben ser capaces de tener valores.

Otra cosa, comprueba que estás mirando en los archivos correctos. Pues la salida de var_dump muestra claves como idioma, dni, pais, etc. Pero en el form que nos estás mostrando no hay ningún valor con un name que contenga ninguna de esas claves. Entonces, o bien estás verificando en el lugar equivocado, o bien el programa está tomando un código antiguo, guardado en la memoria cache. El manejo de que haces de $_POST supongo que lo estás haciendo en el archivo que está en esta ruta ./php/usuario_guardar.php

@A.Cedano entiendo todo loq me comunicas,  el tags q me mencionas no se ve puse todos los  name en el form nada, y los elementos que  mencionas si existen en el formulario solo q no los puse para mayor claridad, el tema esta en comprender el error. todo era funcional hasta que cambie ese campo con js  lo puse mas interactivo lo que ves en el ejemplo  se comunica con el form y trae la info, en si seria entender este input donde guarda por mas que le pongo los name de todos esos elementos no trae el dato con el vard.. que me enviaste lo evidencie

@A.Cedano yo creo en mi ignorancia que el dato se lo esta quedando el code js entonces si quieres te  comparto ese dato, muchas gracias por el apoyo

Por lo que comentas entiendo que estarías usando Ajax o la API Fetch de Javascript para enviar los datos al servidor. Si es así, entonces está claro que deberías agregar ese código a la pregunta para ver qué es lo que está ocurriendo. Cuando preguntes aquí debes poner todo el contexto, para que podamos analizar el problema de una manera global.

@A.Cedano hola ahi inclui el codigo js que faltaba quedare atento a tus comentarios, gracias

Hola. El código .js que has compartido es irrelevante para lo que nos ocupa, porque ese código no manda nada al servidor. El contexto que necesitamos ver es el envío de datos desde el cliente hacia el servidor. ¿Cuál es el código que hace dicho envío?

@A.Cedano pues ese el todo el codigo tengo, el codigo de enviar es el del princio que es guardar.php, no sabria entocnces como capturar la informaccion, porque segun las pruebas que me indicaste variable global existe en .js tag, que se crea como ves cada ves que elijo  la opcion, la verdad no sabria en ese caso como capturar el dato, sacar del html y llevarlo al php sin perder las etiquetas, gracias

Yo quiero saber de dónde salen estos datos array(9) {          ["idioma"]=> string(10) "Papiamento"      ["dni"]=> string(13) "1223345566678"      ["pais"]=> string(7) "Albania"      ["nombres"]=> string(6) "efverg"      ["tags"]=> string(41) "Dancers, Entrepreneurs, Cosplay, For Kids"  ["apellidos"]=> string(10) "efhefheuhr"      ["email"]=> string(24) "kjfjbf45555bfs@gmail.com"      ["usuario_clave_1"]=> string(7) "1234567"      ["usuario_clave_2"]=> string(7) "1234567" } string(0) "". En todo el código que has compartido, no se ve que mandes esos datos en ninguna parte ...

... lo cual dificulta poder analizar el problema de una forma global para saber dónde está el error. Puede que en tu contexto estén interviniendo otros archivos. Revisa el código fuente en la consola del navegador, o bien revisa los include o require que haces en tu código. Debes tomar en mano el contexto, es decir, saber qué hace tu código y de dónde viene cada cosa para poder depurarlo adecuadamente. Otra opción que deberías considerar es revisar el log de errores, que te informará con claridad del origen de cada error en tu código. Ahora estás depurando a ciegas.
